# MS botbuilder Skype calling bot example

Tags: node.js, botframework

After installing this nodejs calling [bot example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/6c26390efca47f04a80ab37e86ca77ee725e88c6/Node/examples/demo-skype-calling/app.js)
bot works and after Skype user calls it plays default menu, but after that when user say one of the options nothing happens, it just play menu again after a while.
Find more details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4521)

Anyone managed to activate next step of waterfall?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bot Builder SDK for Node.js (more details are in the Github link I left) but I already found a problem and will give more details in answer, thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of twist and turns and some strange implications on my own code, where I used segments from example I mentioned in my question, it turns out that the problem I experienced was related with token and **nbf** time (defines the time before which the *jwt* must not be accepted) stopping my workflow. I managed to overcome the problem by using *clockTolerance* option in *CallConnector.js* file. So, instead of doing this (140 line):

```
decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret);
```

just add options part:

```
decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret, jwtVerifyOptions);
```

where jwtVerifyOptions could be specified like this:

```
const jwtVerifyOptions = {
    ignoreExpiration: false,
    ignoreNotBefore: false,
    clockTolerance: 300
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced this issue.it's related to a change to our state service.
you can add below line before begin with bot.dialog

```
bot.set('storage', new builder.MemoryBotStorage());
```